# Error in a script written in Python. Can someone tel the syntax error here

Tags: syntax

This is a programme written using Python language. When I run this on IQ Option broker, I got the following error message.

" Syntax error near talib " Can someone correct this for me???

import talib
import iqoptionapi

## Connect to IQ Option API

api = iqoptionapi.API("username", "password")

## Define instrument

instrument = {
"name": "Higher Option",
"icon": "indicators:EMA",
"overlay": False
}

## Define candle interval

interval = "1m"

## Define trade size

trade_size = 10

## Define EMA periods

ema_periods = [21, 50, 100]

while True:
# Get latest candle
candles = api.get_candles("EURUSD", interval)
latest_candle = candles[-1]

```
# Calculate EMAs
emas = [talib.EMA(candles["close"], timeperiod=period)[-1] for period in ema_periods]

# Check if opening price is above EMAs
if latest_candle["open"] > min(emas):
    # Check if closing price is above previous candle's closing price
    if latest_candle["close"] > candles[-2]["close"]:
        # Place trade
        api.buy("EURUSD", trade_size, "call")
```

I tried to run this on IQ Option broker.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote two time `import`

`Import talib import iqoptionapi`

Maybe try to write like this :

`from talib import iqoptionapi`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).